# Kendo - Reccurrence Editor - changing date format causes the value not post back to server

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, recurrence

I changed the date format as shown on the picture.

[image]

the following code was applied to get the above achieved result:

```
$("div#Recurrence").find(":input[data-role=datepicker]").kendoDatePicker({
                        format: "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                        parseFormats: ["M/d/yyyy"]
                    });
```

Even if I try to call kendo.init() on that control - does not change the situation.
Anytime I post the recurrence editor value back to server the value is set to event date instead of the selected value:

[image]

Is there any way how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that re-initializing the DateTimePicker makes the RecurrenceEditor lose track of it. How about just using setOptions?

```
$("div#Recurrence").find(":input[data-role=datepicker]").data('kendoDatePicker').setOptions({
                    format: "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                    parseFormats: ["M/d/yyyy"]
                });
```

Comment: The `setOptions(..)` is very useful!  This post led me to an answer for how to dynamically set the minimum allowed date using the min property in a the date picker (needed to set it to today to prohibit user from selecting past date).